# Table support for AngularJS Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I would like to create a table using Angular Material.

I am not able to find a table implementation from the documentation.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

However, I found other implementations. I am confused. Are these implementations from Google? Can they work with Angular Material?

https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table

http://codepen.io/jbltx/details/WbdRRb

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);
```

Comment: No they are independent libraries based on angular.

Comment: Although old topic and old version of Angular 1.x, I want to share my experience with https://github.com/iamisti/mdDataTable (mentioned as an answer below) and https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table mentioned by you: the solution from daniel-nagy repo was a better fit, maybe because of the smaller dependencies it has and I could achieve the results I needed by using it. A feature that I am not sure is misses is the "select displayed columns" which "iamisti" repo has.

Answer (score 6):

There is no official angular material table yet,
But there are some folks who created some on their own to fill that gap.
I really suggest this one:
https://github.com/iamisti/mdDataTable

Since this has been implemented exactly the way it is written in the specification of google material.

Comment: I would find very helpful if you could also provide more details about why were needed extra libraries (like jquery, underscore, lodash) ? I was expecting that angular to already provide all needed functions to parse, sort and display the data.

Comment: Also, tried to integrate with the latest AngularJS (1.7.2) and there were some incompatibilities that triggered errors in console (eg. length check on undefined elements, etc). If there is no plan in updating it, I would not recommend trying to integrate because behavior is not known and debugging may take too much time.

Comment: yes, you right. I'm not maintaining it anymore. There is very good solutions like ng-smart-table, for angular 2+, and I believe no one should use angular 1 anymore.